# Missing required parameter for [Route: storage_file][URL: files/{filename}] [Missing parameter: filename]

Tags: laravel, github

[When I add a table to display an image suddenly an error message appears like this. Please help with the solution. To see the image please click on this text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skelS.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: Show us the code, specially the view and the route.

Comment: Well you do not pass the filename parameter when calling the route. Without the code we can't really help.

Comment: You are likely creating a `route('storage_file')` link somewhere in your template where you should create the link like this: `route('storage_file', $filename)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.